# Loading an Integer Array into a SIMD register

Tags: c, sse, simd

at the moment I'm trying to load an integer array into a SIMD register using SSE.
I have an aligned 32-bit integer array `Ai` and want to load 4 consecutive elements into a SIMD register `Xi`. However, the values stored in `Xi` after executing `_mm_load_si128` are garbage except for the first one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

// number has to be divisible by 4 without remainder
#define VECTOR_SIZE 8

int main() {

    __attribute__((aligned (16))) int32_t *Ai = (int32_t*) malloc(VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(int32_t));

    for(int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; i++) {
        Ai[i] = rand() % 100000;
    }

    __m128i Xi;

    for(int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; i+=4) {
        Xi = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*) &Ai[i]);

        // show content of Xi and Ai
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("Xi[%d] = %d\t Ai[%d] = %d\n", j, Xi[j], i+j, Ai[i+j]);
        }
    }

    free(Ai);
}
```

Here is an example output:

```
Xi[0] = 16807    Ai[0] = 16807
Xi[1] = 50073    Ai[1] = 75249
Xi[2] = 1489217992   Ai[2] = 50073
Xi[3] = 1346391152   Ai[3] = 43658
Xi[0] = 8930     Ai[4] = 8930
Xi[1] = 27544    Ai[5] = 11272
Xi[2] = 1489217992   Ai[6] = 27544
Xi[3] = 1346391168   Ai[7] = 50878
```

What is wrong?

Comment: If you enabled compiler warnings, you'd notice that `Xi` is treated as a vector of `long long int`, so in your `printf()`, `Xi[j]` is a `long long int`, which causes undefined behavior as `printf("...%d...",...)` expects an `int`. In this case, `printf()` truncates the value and this causes it to *look like* the first value is correct, but it really is not.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant this when you were coming up with your example:

```
union {
    __m128i m128;
    int32_t i32[4];
} Xi;

for(int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; i+=4) {
    Xi.m128 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*) &Ai[i]);

    // show content of Xi and Ai
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        printf("Xi[%d] = %d\t Ai[%d] = %d\n", j, Xi.i32[j], i+j, Ai[i+j]);
    }
}
```

Here is the example output:

```
Xi[0] = 89383    Ai[0] = 89383
Xi[1] = 30886    Ai[1] = 30886
Xi[2] = 92777    Ai[2] = 92777
Xi[3] = 36915    Ai[3] = 36915
Xi[0] = 47793    Ai[4] = 47793
Xi[1] = 38335    Ai[5] = 38335
Xi[2] = 85386    Ai[6] = 85386
Xi[3] = 60492    Ai[7] = 60492
```

Comment: Note that `__m128i::i32` is an MSVC extension, and not portable.  Use `_mm_extract_epi32(vec, 0..3)`, or look at your vectors in a debugger.